# Does postman support read data from excel file?

Tags: postman

We have sets of json data stored in excel file.
I'm using POI apache library and classes to call the excel specific column. And parse it as API request body.
Does postman has such feature which allow me to do the same way?

Example:

1. json data for POST is stored in excel column A1
2. At Postman test script, call the data from excel
3. Parse it as request body

Comment: With the collection runner you can load data from a CSV or JSON file, but not from Postman directly or from an Excel file.